# An approximation variant of the halting problem

Tags: undecidability, approximation, halting-problem

It always has been bugging me that we (humans) know pretty easily when most programs we write halt or not, but the halting problem is still undecidable.

I have just thought of a variant approximation-like extension to this problem, that tries to "maximize" the correct answers an algorithm can make on this problem.

Formally speaking, let us say that a turing machine $A$ that **always halts**, is $r$-solving the halting problem, for $r\colon \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, if $$r(n)\le |\{x\in \Sigma^*\mid x\text{ is a TM}\space\land\space|x|\le n\space \land\space A(x) \text{ is correct}\}|$$ where $A(x)$ is said to be correct $\iff$ $A(x)$ outputs *true* for $x\in HALT$ and outputs *false* otherwise.

Equivalently, we can define $r$ to be a function $r\colon \mathbb{N}\rightarrow [0,1]$ and then the requirement will change to $t(n)\cdot r(n) \le \cdots$, where $t(n)$ is the number of Turing machines that are encoded into strings no longer than $n$.

**My question is:** What is the largest $r$ function that we have an $r$-solving algorithm for? Or, what is the highest $r$ function that we can have an $r$-solving efficient (e.g. polynomial) algorithm for? Or are there other known things about the behavior of $r$-solving algorithms?

---

This can be easily adapted to any other problem, so I would be glad for any answer that explains this on any interesting language, and not necessarily the halting problem

Comment: It's possible that the reason we usually know the answer is that we typically only write programs that we can be confident are correct (and thus where we know whether they should terminate or not; assuming our understanding is accurate).  One shortcoming of your formulation is that "nearly all" strings of a certain length represent only a boring Turing machine (e.g., one that has a syntax error, or one that immediately terminates), so the uniform distribution on strings doesn't match the natural distribution programs seen in the real world.

Comment: Just to mention dead-simple algorithm for which the halting property is not known : take as input $n$ and compute the sequence of the Collatz conjecture starting at $n$ until you reach $1$.

Comment: The answer depends on the encoding. For example, consider any encoding $\pi\colon \mathbb{N} \to \text{TMs}$ of Turing machines. We can define an encoding $\sigma\colon \{0,1\}^* \to \text{TMs}$ by $\sigma(0^n) = \pi(n)$ and $\sigma(w) = \pi(0)$ otherwise. This gives $r(n) \geq 2^n-1$. In contrast, if $\sigma(w) = \pi(|w|)$ then $r(n) = 0$ infinitely often for any $A$.

Comment: In your second definition, you need to normalize $r(n)$ by $|\Sigma|^n$ rather than by $n$.

Comment: You can ask what happens for a Kolmogorov complexity-style admissible encoding — perhaps this is more well-behaved.

Comment: Many unsolved mathematical problems can be translated to the halting problem. Easy to write a program that halts for every input iff the Collatz conjecture is true.

Comment: What im interested in is not a specific problem / a way to create such problems (also, the collatz conjecture is just unsolved, it could be that someone will prove it always halts) but rather im interested in the best "approximation" we can use to decide the halting property of programs, i.e, what algorithm will yield the maximal "correct" outputs for programs (of course, it can never be perfect, i just wonder how far it really is from being "perfect")